# How to optimize this asp.net code for several future years?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having this code below and I am using the same for binding it to a dropdown in asp.net mvc.
It works fine...
For several years with IDs,It wont be a good idea to add each year manually.
what I want is to optimize the code or reduce the code using for loop or something and then pass the list to the view.

```
 var list = new SelectList(new[] 
           {
               new { ID = "1", Name = "2015" },
                new { ID = "2", Name = "2016" },
            new { ID = "3", Name = "2017" },
        },
            "ID", "Name", 2);

        ViewBag.YearIn = list;
        return View();
```

Comment: Why do you need an `ID` (why not just a list of years)? - you could simple use `IEnumable.Range(2015, 50)` to generate the next 50 years

Comment: I used IDs for selecting a particular  year by default, as in the above case I am passing 2 i.e selecting 2016 by default on my dropdown.

Comment: But why. If you choose `2016`, why would you want to post back `2` instead of `2106` (what possible meaning would a value of `2` have?) And if you just want to choose a default, then make the default 2016, not 2.

Comment: I am bit new to this...can you give an example?

Comment: `ViewBag.YearList = new SelectList(IEnumerable.Range(2015, 30));` and then in the view, `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, (SelectList)ViewBag.YearList)` - and if the value of property `Year` is 2016, then the second option will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could implement that. It's not good to assume you're always going to start at 2015. So you could replace the `const int StartYear` with `DateTime.Now.Year` if you wanted to start at the current year.

You can also set a total amount of years in the future you'd like to use.

```
const int StartYear = 2015;
const int TotalYears = 3;
var years = new System.Collections.Generic.List<object>();

for (int id = 1, year = StartYear; id <= TotalYears; id++, year++)
{
    years.Add(new { ID = Convert.ToString(id), Name = Convert.ToString(year) });
}

var list = new SelectList(years, "ID", "Name", 2);
```

Comment: this will not work after 2015 because in 2016 it will still show 2015 as first year @akash check my answer

Comment: In my answer, I explained that it's "not good to assume you're always going to start at 2015". If that's the case, I recommend @akash "replace the `const int StartYear` with `DateTime.Now.Year`".

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 2015; i < 2030; i++)
    list.Add(new { Id = i-2014, Name = i });
```

Something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this `DateTime.Now.Year` to get the current year and then number of years you want to add as per scenario

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
int uptoyear= year+10;//or it depends on scenario

var years = new System.Collections.Generic.List<object>();

for (var i = year; i <= uptoyear; i++)
years.Add(new { ID = Convert.ToString(i-(year-1)), Name = Convert.ToString(year) });

var list = new SelectList(years, "ID", "Name", 1);
```

Comment: how to declare the list but?

Comment: @akash Check my answer out. It declares a list for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enumerable.Range to automatically generate a list of numbers.

Also, use DateTime.Now.Year to start the list with the curren year, if needed.

Code sample working fine:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EnkJOB